# Postgresql row-level security generates different query plan from manually inserted WHERE clause

Tags: performance, execution-plan, postgresql-9.5, row-level-security, query-performance

(Copied from my post to the postgresql mailing list https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADBa3wZpuYXwdry2g68NxYmAXOPvx0DLvdAU4kdo2GoPtxKu+Q@mail.gmail.com. Unfortunately I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links so please refer to the original post for more links)

Basic summary of the problem:
Using a row-level security filter on one column in a 12GB table results in a slow bitmap heap scan instead of the fast index scan used by the query executed as the owner of the table (without any row-level security). Writing in the filter condition by hand also results in a fast index scan. Cf. https://gist.github.com/charles-cooper/abccf41ce5a1175635414321622fba57 for all the code in this post.

The table description is as follows:

```
 Table "data.sm2dvmoam"
  Column   |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 item      | smallint                    | not null  | plain   |              | 
 secid     | integer                     | not null  | plain   |              | 
 startdate | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain   |              | 
 enddate   | timestamp without time zone |           | plain   |              | 
 value_    | real                        |           | plain   |              | 
 licflag   | smallint                    | not null  | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "sm2dvmoam_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (item, secid, startdate)
    "sm2dvmoam_secid_item_idx" btree (secid, item)
Policies:
    POLICY "policy_qai_U0002_56000_1" FOR SELECT
      TO qai_U0002
      USING (((licflag = 1) AND true))
    POLICY "policy_qai_U0002_56000_3" FOR SELECT
      TO qai_U0002
      USING (((licflag = 3) AND true))
    POLICY "policy_qai_U0002_56300_2" FOR SELECT
      TO qai_U0002
      USING (((licflag = 2) AND true))
    POLICY "policy_qai_U0002_56300_3" FOR SELECT
      TO qai_U0002
      USING (((licflag = 3) AND true))
elsendb=> \dt+ sm2dvmoam

List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  | Owner | Size  | Description 
--------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------------
 data   | sm2dvmoam | table | app   | 12 GB | 
(1 row)
```

The original query can be found here:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
select
  s.eid
  , cast(foo.startdate as date)
  , foo.value_::float8
from vw_secmap s
join lateral (
select tbl.startdate, tbl.value_
from sm2DVMOam tbl
join sm2item i
    on i.item = tbl.item
join sm2dinfo si ON
  si.secid = tbl.secid

where si.secid = s.vencode
  and tbl.item = 161        --starmine code for table
  and tbl.startdate between '2000-12-31' and '2100-01-01'

) foo on
  ventype = 23
  --and s.rank=1
where s.eid in (1011103444,1011104467,1011107316,1011107487,1011108370,1011110098,1011113327,1011118705,1011123638,1011129247,1011129271,1011133380,1011133542,1011133548,1011133769,1011134126,1011135165,1011135316,1011135554,1011136443,1011136514,1011136531,1011136747,1011137714,1011137923,1011140099,1011141027,1011141091,1011141262,1011141279,1011141583,1011142199,1011142848,1011143861,1011143894,1011144465,1011147311,1011148404,1011149266,1011149294,1011149443,1011149457,1011149576,1011150581,1011150590,1011151010,1011152042,1011153318,1011153534,1011153782,1011157053,1011158430,1011158763) --seccode
```

The query with the filter spliced in by hand can be found here:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
select
  s.eid
  , cast(foo.startdate as date)
  , foo.value_::float8
from vw_secmap s
join lateral (
select tbl.startdate, tbl.value_
from sm2DVMOam tbl
join sm2item i
    on i.item = tbl.item
join sm2dinfo si ON
  si.secid = tbl.secid

where si.secid = s.vencode
  and tbl.item = 161        --starmine code for table
  and tbl.startdate between '2000-12-31' and '2100-01-01'
  and (licflag = 1 OR licflag = 3 OR licflag = 2 OR licflag = 3)

) foo on
  ventype = 23
  --and s.rank=1
where s.eid in (1011103444,1011104467,1011107316,1011107487,1011108370,1011110098,1011113327,1011118705,1011123638,1011129247,1011129271,1011133380,1011133542,1011133548,1011133769,1011134126,1011135165,1011135316,1011135554,1011136443,1011136514,1011136531,1011136747,1011137714,1011137923,1011140099,1011141027,1011141091,1011141262,1011141279,1011141583,1011142199,1011142848,1011143861,1011143894,1011144465,1011147311,1011148404,1011149266,1011149294,1011149443,1011149457,1011149576,1011150581,1011150590,1011151010,1011152042,1011153318,1011153534,1011153782,1011157053,1011158430,1011158763) --seccode
```

And the query which uses the row-based mechanism here:

```
SET ROLE "qai_U0002";
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
select
  s.eid
  , cast(foo.startdate as date)
  , foo.value_::float8
from vw_secmap s
join lateral (
select tbl.startdate, tbl.value_
from sm2DVMOam tbl
join sm2item i
    on i.item = tbl.item
join sm2dinfo si ON
  si.secid = tbl.secid

where si.secid = s.vencode
  and tbl.item = 161        --starmine code for table
  and tbl.startdate between '2000-12-31' and '2100-01-01'

) foo on
  ventype = 23
  --and s.rank=1
where s.eid in (1011103444,1011104467,1011107316,1011107487,1011108370,1011110098,1011113327,1011118705,1011123638,1011129247,1011129271,1011133380,1011133542,1011133548,1011133769,1011134126,1011135165,1011135316,1011135554,1011136443,1011136514,1011136531,1011136747,1011137714,1011137923,1011140099,1011141027,1011141091,1011141262,1011141279,1011141583,1011142199,1011142848,1011143861,1011143894,1011144465,1011147311,1011148404,1011149266,1011149294,1011149443,1011149457,1011149576,1011150581,1011150590,1011151010,1011152042,1011153318,1011153534,1011153782,1011157053,1011158430,1011158763) --seccode
```

The query plans are below.
Original query plan:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=1.29..442.22 rows=65 width=20) (actual time=0.293..17.936 rows=14556 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1034
   ->  Seq Scan on sm2item i  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=0.049..0.055 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (item = 161)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 181
         Buffers: shared hit=2
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.29..436.97 rows=65 width=22) (actual time=0.224..13.539 rows=14556 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=1032
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..268.41 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.126..1.242 rows=53 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=289
               ->  Index Scan using vw_secmap_ventype_eid_idx on vw_secmap s  (cost=0.43..251.13 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.077..0.710 rows=53 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((ventype = 23) AND (eid = ANY ('{1011103444,1011104467,1011107316,1011107487,1011108370,1011110098,1011113327,1011118705,1011123638,1011129247,1011129271,1011133380,1011133542,1011133548,1011133769,1011134126,1011135165,1011135316,1011135554,1011136443,1011136514,1011136531,1011136747,1011137714,1011137923,1011140099,1011141027,1011141091,1011141262,1011141279,1011141583,1011142199,1011142848,1011143861,1011143894,1011144465,1011147311,1011148404,1011149266,1011149294,1011149443,1011149457,1011149576,1011150581,1011150590,1011151010,1011152042,1011153318,1011153534,1011153782,1011157053,1011158430,1011158763}'::bigint[])))
                     Buffers: shared hit=182
               ->  Index Only Scan using sm2dinfo_pkey on sm2dinfo si  (cost=0.29..4.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=53)
                     Index Cond: (secid = s.vencode)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
                     Buffers: shared hit=107
         ->  Index Scan using sm2dvmoam_pkey on sm2dvmoam tbl  (cost=0.57..147.05 rows=2151 width=18) (actual time=0.032..0.173 rows=275 loops=53)
               Index Cond: ((item = 161) AND (secid = si.secid) AND (startdate >= '2000-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (startdate <= '2100-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Buffers: shared hit=743
 Planning time: 3.150 ms
 Execution time: 18.999 ms
(22 rows)
```

Query plan with manual filter:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=1.29..460.50 rows=56 width=20) (actual time=0.302..20.151 rows=14556 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1034
   ->  Seq Scan on sm2item i  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=0.049..0.055 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (item = 161)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 181
         Buffers: shared hit=2
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.29..455.39 rows=56 width=22) (actual time=0.234..16.123 rows=14556 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=1032
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..268.41 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.122..1.246 rows=53 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=289
               ->  Index Scan using vw_secmap_ventype_eid_idx on vw_secmap s  (cost=0.43..251.13 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.082..0.710 rows=53 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((ventype = 23) AND (eid = ANY ('{1011103444,1011104467,1011107316,1011107487,1011108370,1011110098,1011113327,1011118705,1011123638,1011129247,1011129271,1011133380,1011133542,1011133548,1011133769,1011134126,1011135165,1011135316,1011135554,1011136443,1011136514,1011136531,1011136747,1011137714,1011137923,1011140099,1011141027,1011141091,1011141262,1011141279,1011141583,1011142199,1011142848,1011143861,1011143894,1011144465,1011147311,1011148404,1011149266,1011149294,1011149443,1011149457,1011149576,1011150581,1011150590,1011151010,1011152042,1011153318,1011153534,1011153782,1011157053,1011158430,1011158763}'::bigint[])))
                     Buffers: shared hit=182
               ->  Index Only Scan using sm2dinfo_pkey on sm2dinfo si  (cost=0.29..4.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=53)
                     Index Cond: (secid = s.vencode)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
                     Buffers: shared hit=107
         ->  Index Scan using sm2dvmoam_pkey on sm2dvmoam tbl  (cost=0.57..168.56 rows=1842 width=18) (actual time=0.032..0.233 rows=275 loops=53)
               Index Cond: ((item = 161) AND (secid = si.secid) AND (startdate >= '2000-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (startdate <= '2100-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Filter: ((licflag = 1) OR (licflag = 3) OR (licflag = 2) OR (licflag = 3))
               Buffers: shared hit=743
 Planning time: 3.163 ms
 Execution time: 21.171 ms
(23 rows)
```

The plan using row-level security:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=809369.94..3453685.86 rows=56 width=20) (actual time=3914.370..11950.555 rows=14556 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=301690
   ->  Seq Scan on sm2item i  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=0.064..0.069 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (item = 161)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 181
         Buffers: shared hit=2
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=809369.94..3453680.75 rows=56 width=22) (actual time=3914.286..11947.449 rows=14556 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (tbl.secid = si.secid)
         Buffers: shared hit=301688
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on sm2dvmoam tbl  (cost=809101.52..3151195.86 rows=21979157 width=18) (actual time=3128.354..9915.334 rows=24819619 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((item = 161) AND (startdate >= '2000-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (startdate <= '2100-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Filter: ((licflag = 3) OR (licflag = 2) OR (licflag = 3) OR (licflag = 1))
               Heap Blocks: exact=192031
               Buffers: shared hit=301396
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sm2dvmoam_pkey  (cost=0.00..803606.73 rows=25654594 width=0) (actual time=3037.394..3037.394 rows=24827083 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((item = 161) AND (startdate >= '2000-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (startdate <= '2100-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                     Buffers: shared hit=109365
         ->  Hash  (cost=268.41..268.41 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=1.539..1.539 rows=53 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
               Buffers: shared hit=289
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..268.41 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.151..1.508 rows=53 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=289
                     ->  Index Scan using vw_secmap_ventype_eid_idx on vw_secmap s  (cost=0.43..251.13 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.100..0.877 rows=53 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((ventype = 23) AND (eid = ANY ('{1011103444,1011104467,1011107316,1011107487,1011108370,1011110098,1011113327,1011118705,1011123638,1011129247,1011129271,1011133380,1011133542,1011133548,1011133769,1011134126,1011135165,1011135316,1011135554,1011136443,1011136514,1011136531,1011136747,1011137714,1011137923,1011140099,1011141027,1011141091,1011141262,1011141279,1011141583,1011142199,1011142848,1011143861,1011143894,1011144465,1011147311,1011148404,1011149266,1011149294,1011149443,1011149457,1011149576,1011150581,1011150590,1011151010,1011152042,1011153318,1011153534,1011153782,1011157053,1011158430,1011158763}'::bigint[])))
                           Buffers: shared hit=182
                     ->  Index Only Scan using sm2dinfo_pkey on sm2dinfo si  (cost=0.29..4.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=53)
                           Index Cond: (secid = s.vencode)
                           Heap Fetches: 0
                           Buffers: shared hit=107
 Planning time: 3.417 ms
 Execution time: 11953.125 ms
(31 rows)
```

pgsql version: 9.5.3
OS: Ubuntu Xenial 16.04, kernel 3.14.32

Why is the plan generated using RLS so much less efficient than using the hand-generated query?